# SquidIndex can't be null error while running Sonar Analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project in Jenkins 1.545.I am using Sonarqube version 4.2.I have installed cobertura plugin version 1.6.1 and java plugin version 2.2.1 in Sonarqube.For sonar analysis,i have set the maven build option as sonar:sonar with properties as below:
    sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
    sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
    sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
My jenkins build fail with the following error in the console output:-
    parsing {$MyPath}/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
    [ERROR] SquidIndex can't be null
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) 
    on project ing-top-level: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: SquidIndex can't be null

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered on that topic on the mailing list. http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SquidIndex-can-t-be-null-error-while-running-Sonar-Analysis-td5025655.html

Comment: Hi, I saw the reason for this error on link mentioned by Benzonico but is there a workaround to resolve this? I have a similar issue . I tried adding the step "mvn <-D<modulename>>.cobertura.skip=true install but it didn't work.
"

Comment: Any other workaround except for putting a dummy java file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when there is a cobertura report and no java files in a module. 
Ticket has been created : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3750

Two workaround that might work while waiting for the ticket to be fixed :

- Put a dummy java file in your maven module
- Do not generate a coverage report for this module, so the cobertura sensor won't execute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the first workaround of putting an empty java file but it then showed this error:Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project <project name>-top-level: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Can not execute Findbugs: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled classes. -> [Help 1]

Comment: I am also facing the same error while running sonar analysis using the first workaround of putting dummy java file.